# Empty string passed to getElementById() on custom js

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementbyid

i have a custom build js file for a web application. What i get on firefox console is the message "Empty string passed to getElementById()" on a particular line of the code. the error counting, is added by four(4) on every click..at some point the browser starts stucking until it alerts with an error "script has stopped working or is busy on line:36, stop script, or continue"
The line  is:
`if(o=a.getElementById(i[2]),o&&o.parentNode){`

Some of the code:

```
q=function(e){(a.addEventListener||"load"===e.type||"complete"===a.readyState)&&(_(),x.ready())},
_=function(){a.addEventListener?(a.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",q,!1),

e.removeEventListener("load",q,!1)):(a.detachEvent("onreadystatechange",q),
e.detachEvent("onload",q))};
x.fn=x.prototype={jquery:f,constructor:x,
init:function(e,n,r){var i,o;if(!e)return this;if("string"==typeof e){
    if(i="<"===e.charAt(0)&&">"===e.charAt(e.length-1)&&e.length>=3?[null,e,null]:N.exec(e),!i||!i[1]&&n)
    return!n||n.jquery?(n||r).find(e):this.constructor(n).find(e);
    if(i[1]){
        if(n=n instanceof x?n[0]:n,
        x.merge(this,
        x.parseHTML(i[1],
        n&&n.nodeType?n.ownerDocument||n:a,!0)),
    k.test(i[1])&&x.isPlainObject(n))
    for(i in n)x.isFunction(this[i])?this[i](n[i]):this.attr(i,n[i]);return this}

>>>>>This line error>>>>>> if(o=a.getElementById(i[2]),o&&o.parentNode){

        if(o.id!==i[2])return r.find(e);this.length=1,this[0]=o}
        return this.context=a,
        this.selector=e,this}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you posted non-minified JS. Keeping track of all those 1-letter variables is a real brain drain.

Comment: This is jQuery's document.ready function minified isn't it? You probably have an error elsewhere, it's just showing up as an internal jQuery error, probably because you did a booboo somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be the problem:

```
for(i in n)x.isFunction(this[i])?this[i](n[i]):this.attr(i,n[i]);return this}
```

`i` was previously an array, but this is reusing the variable as the index of the loop. When the loop is done, `i` contains the last property name in `n` instead of the original array, but the next line expects it to still contain the original array.

Use a variable name that doesn't conflict with another variable in the function.

Comment: the error comes up on jquery.min v.1.10.2, the custom js is applied to jquery.min using +function($){"use strict";....the error continues...after some time, the browser(firefox) fails..

Comment: What's your point? When you modified the function, you reused one of its variable names, and this is interfering with its normal use of that variable. Use a different variable and you should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

The script was applying a function with ajax call, on document load, along with an interval of 1 minute for notifications. I changed the interval to Timeout inside the ajax success result, now it works and doesn't fail the browser..